# Simplify query from select in select to use join

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I have two tables like this:

```
Room
-----------------
id
```

and

```
Reservation
-----------------
id
room_id
check_in
check_out
```

I aim to get all rooms which have no reservation, during a specific check_in and check_out period.

So far, I have managed to build the query like this:

```
select * from room
where room.id not in (
select room2.id from room as room2
inner join reservation r on room2.id = r.room_id
where r.check_in > '2020-04-19' and r.check_out < '2020-04-25');
```

But I believe there must be a more optimal way to do this, using left join.

How can I build an equivalent query, using just joins?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a `LEFT JOIN` where you filter out all the matching rows:

```
select rm.* 
from room rm left join reservation rs
on rs.room_id = rm.room_id and rs.check_in > '2020-04-19' and rs.check_out < '2020-04-25'
where rs.room_id is null
```

As you can see all the conditions must be placed in the `ON` clause.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest `not exists`:

```
select r.*
from room r
where not exists (select 1
                  from reservation res
                  where r.id = res.room_id and
                        res.check_in > '2020-04-19' and
                        res.check_out < '2020-04-25'
                 );
```

Note that there is no need for a `join` in the subquery (nor in your version, but I strongly discourage `not in` with subqueries because of the treatment of `null` values).

In terms of performance, this should be better than or comparable to `left join` in most databases.  It can take advantage of an index on `reservations(room_id, check_in, check_out)`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `not in` approach doesn't need a `join` and could have been expressed this way. **Only use this if you are certain you don't have any null values** for the relevant columns in the reservation table.

```
select * 
from room
where id not in (select room_id 
                  from reservation
                  where check_in > '2020-04-19' and check_out < '2020-04-25');
```

If you insist on using a `join`

```
select t1.*
from room t1
inner join (select distinct room_id 
            from reservation 
            where check_in <= '2020-04-19' and check_out >= '2020-04-25') t2     
on t1.id=t2.room_id
```

Comment: I think, given the title 'Simplify query from select in select to use join', the OP expects to solve this, using only joins.

Comment: XY Problems are not uncommon on Stackoverflow. I could be wrong, but I think OP wanted to simplify his query and may have thought joins is the way to go. I did add an approach using joins in case you didn't notice.